# Displaying the 0 in front of a number

Tags: php, mysql, number-formatting

I'm generating auto incremental code through a PHP script. The sequence goes like this, **L001**, **L002**....**L039**, **L040**. Below is the PHP code I have written. The comments show the output of each statement.

```
<?php

require_once("db_handler.php");

$conn = iniCon();
$db = selectDB($conn);

$query = "SELECT LID FROM locations ORDER BY LID DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$last_id = $row['LID'];   //L040

$id_letter = substr($last_id, 0, 1);  //L
$id_num = substr($last_id, 1) + 1;   //040 + 1
$new_id = $id_letter . $id_num;

mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

I'm displaying the `$new_id` in a HTML textbox. though everything works fine up to this point,  the new generated code shows as **L41**, cutting off the leading zero.

How can I stop this from happening? I need to have that zero in the front.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either `str_pad` or `sprintf` function:

```
$id_num = str_pad($id_num, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

or

```
$id_num = sprintf("%03d", $id_num);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$id_num = substr($last_id, 1) + 1;   //40 + 1

$id_num = str_pad($id_num, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); //return 041

$new_id = $id_letter . $id_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at sprintf[1]. hint: %03d

[1] https://www.php.net/sprintf